# Updated summary table from an hourly table

Tags: sql, oracle

i have this hourly table that fetches new data each hour,

```
pid start_date        end_date 
1   09-JUN-20 12:03   09-JUN-20 12:06
1   09-JUN-20 12:09   09-JUN-20 12:12
2   09-JUN-20 12:01   09-JUN-20 12:03
2   09-JUN-20 12:06   09-JUN-20 12:15
2   09-JUN-20 12:16   09-JUN-20 12:18
```

this table has different data each hour 
i want to issue this summary table:

```
pid occurrences
1   2
2   3
```

but in the next hour data will change to this:

```
1   09-JUN-20 13:03   09-JUN-20 13:06
2   09-JUN-20 13:01   09-JUN-20 13:01
2   09-JUN-20 13:01   09-JUN-20 13:03
2   09-JUN-20 13:06   09-JUN-20 13:15
2   09-JUN-20 13:16   09-JUN-20 13:18
```

the summary table should look like this:

```
pid occurrences
1   3
2   7
```

i managed to do this :

```
SELECT 
  pid,
  count(1) total_flt,

FROM 
  table
GROUP BY
  pid
```

how could i do this process while updating the summary table each hour?

Comment: Are you trying to update it every hour on the hour (so if you looked at 13:59 it would still show a count of 2 for pid 1, and from 14:00 it would show 3), or always have an accurate up-to-date count? Either way you could do this with a view, and if it's an expensive or repetitive query, make it a materialized view.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are asking is how can you generate this result without having to run the query each hour (which could get costly, perhaps, if the table grows very large), then you could maintain a separate table of counts for each `pid` value.

You can create an after insert trigger, which would increment the count for `pid` based on the record which were just inserted.  Then, to get the counts for each `pid`, you would only have to hit the lightweight summary table:

```
SELECT pid, cnt
FROM summmary_table;
```

Here is what that trigger might look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER counts_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON yourTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    UPDATE summary_table
    SET cnt = cnt + 1
    WHERE pid = :new.pid;
END;
```

This assumes that the `summary_table` would already be initialized with each `pid`, starting at a count of zero.

Comment: @Tejash Yes, you are right, I had started off my answer with an insert, but then realized that update was more appropriate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: actually to cover all cases it should probably be a `merge` statement...

Comment: @GMB You caught me off guard, because I have never used merge before.  Yes, it should be an upsert, more generally, but my answer still makes a good suggestion as-is.

Answer (score -1):

The work that you are describing sounds like a materialized view.  This is a query that you can schedule (so it can run once per hour).  It gets materialized like table (so it is fast).  And Oracle takes care of the details, without worrying about triggers, data consistency, and so on.

The basic syntax is easy:

```
create materialized view x
   SELECT pid, count(1) as total_flt,
    FROM table
    GROUP BY pid;
```

However, there is a lot more to it.  You can start by reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REPLN/repmview.htm).